# Why <td th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, table_width)}" th:text="${rows[${i}]}"></td> not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to Iterate through a list which contains a list of objects, i.e.  List I am wondered why this is not working, tried with simply "i", but no luck.

```
List<Object[]> lists;  // logic
model.addObject("lists", lists);
model.addObject("table_width", lists.get(0).length);
```

Thymeleaf Code Snippet

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-stripped table-collapsed table-bordered">
                <tr th:each="rows,rowStat : ${lists}">
                    <td th:text="${rowStat.count}"></td>

                    <td th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, table_width)}" th:text="${rows[${i}]}"></td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way,

```
<td th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, table_width-1)}" th:text="${rows[__${i}__]}"></td>
```

This does the tricks

Comment: In this case, you don't need preprocessing.  You should use `th:text="${rows[i]}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterator over both lists.  No need to use the `#numbers` helper.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-stripped table-collapsed table-bordered">
    <tr th:each="rows, rowStat : ${lists}">
        <td th:text="${rowStat.count}"></td>
        <td th:each="value: ${rows}" th:text="${value}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are iterating a collection(list) of objects, try below example:

HTML:

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(counts)}">
    <h2>Counts List</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="count : ${counts}">
            <td th:text="${count.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${count.name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Java:

```
public List<Count> listAll() {
    List<Count> counts = new ArrayList<>();
    countRepository.findAll().forEach(counts::add);
    return counts;
}
```

Read more info in Thymeleaf Documentation - [Iteration Basics](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics) section.

Comment: Thanks Mebin, I am new in Thymeleaf,  I found the workaround.